# How often does a time period occur in two dates?

Tags: javascript

For a small javascript rental project I would like to know how often a certain time period occurs between two dates. It is possible to specify how long an object should be rented.

There are 4 input fields for the customer:

- PickupDate
- PickupTime
- DropoffDate
- DropffTime

The calculation is based on half and full-day object-reservations

```
1 day:   07:00 - 18:00 = € 30.00
1/2 day: 07:00 - 11:30 = € 15.00
1/2 day: 13:30 - 18:00 = € 15.00
1/2 day: 18:30 - 06:00 = € 15.00
```

An example of such a calculation:

I rent an object on **12.02.2017 08:00** clock until **13.02.2017 10:00** clock.

This would then result in a simple calculation:

```
1x 1 day   (07:00 - 18:00)   € 30.00
1x 1/2 day (18:30 - 06:00)   € 15.00
1x 1/2 day (07:00 - 11:30)   € 15.00
-------------------------------------
                             € 60.00
=====================================
```

Is such a calculation possible so I can see what an object costs?

I am pleased about references or help

Andreas

Comment: Yes, of course, such a calculation is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Currently, I am only able to calculate a daily price:https://jsfiddle.net/ncn9qema/

Comment: Maybe you can give me a hint so I can get the right solution;)